# How to parse a application/x-www-form-urlencoded with an associative array?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

I'm trying to parse the following body:

```
event=invoice.created&data%5Bid%5D=1757E1D7FD5E410A9C563024250015BF&
data%5Bstatus%5D=pending&data%5Baccount_id%5D=70CA234077134ED0BF2E0E46B0EDC36F&
data%5Bsubscription_id%5D=F4115E5E28AE4CCA941FCCCCCABE9A0A
```

Which translates to:

```
event = invoice.created
data[id] = 1757E1D7FD5E410A9C563024250015BF
data[status] = pending
data[account_id] = 70CA234077134ED0BF2E0E46B0EDC36F
data[subscription_id] = F4115E5E28AE4CCA941FCCCCCABE9A0A
```

Code:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE])
fun cb(event: SubscriptionRenewed)
{
    println(event)
}

data class SubscriptionRenewed(
    val event: String,
    val data: Data
)

data class Data(
    val id: String,
    val status: String,
    val account_id: String,
    val subscription_id: String
)
```

Normally you just create a POJO representation of the incoming body and spring a translates it to an object.

I learned that I could add all the parameters to the function declaration as `@RequestParam("data[id]") id: String`, but that would make things really verbose.

The issue is with parsing `data[*]`, ideas of how to make it work?

**Edit:**
I discovered that if I change `val data: Data` to `val data: Map<String, String> = HashMap()`, the associative array will be correctly inserted into the map, ideas of how to map it to an object instead?

***Note:** IDs/Tokens are not real. They are from a documentation snippet.*

Comment: a suggestion: would it be ok to gather as Map<String, String> and use json serialization and deserialization to object?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but it feel like a weird boilerplate when you think about how spring handle other input types.

Answer (score 0):

### Deserialize to Map and use json serialize/deserialize to object

1. Initially deserialize the input to `Map<String, String>`
2. Use Json processor(like `ObjectMapper` or `Gson`) to serialize the `Map` constructed in the previous step
3. Use the json processor to deserialize the json output of previous step to a custom object.

```java
    static class Data {
        private String one;
        private String a;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data{one=" + one + ", a=" + a + "}";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "{\"one\":1, \"a\":\"B\"}";
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(input, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType());
        Data data = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(map), Data.class);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
```

This is surely a round about approach and i am not aware of any optimization